# Is there a possibility to get rid of Error 407 in NPM?`

Tags: npm

there is the following problem:

I am trying to install electron for node.js .I've already downloaded the NPM.
After setting it up, i had to configure our Company Proxy for getting further.

It starts to connect, but stops at some point saying:

> "Error: Tunneling socket could not be established, StatusCode= 407";

Now, i don't know how to get further installing Electron.

Can somebody help me?

Many greetings
Jakob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's proxy issue,these are the workarounds

**Method 1:**

```
npm config set proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport
npm config set https-proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport
```

*Notes:*

For SSL/https proxies, the protocol in URL should be http not https

If your set up is on a Docker/Vagrant instance or a hosted VM, use IP address instead of hostname for proxy as the later might not be resolvable.

If there is no proxy , remove proxy config from npm

```
npm config set proxy null
npm config set https-proxy null
```

**Method 2:**
You have an environment variable called `http_proxy`. Please delete it and try again

**Method 3:** Follow these commands

```
npm config set proxy false
npm cache clean
```

**Method 4:**
Not using any proxy:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

Using Proxy:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxyhostname:proxyport
npm config set https-proxy http://proxyhostname:proxyport
```

For [reference](https://httpstatuses.com/407)

[Closed Issue](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2202)